# Sending telnet commands to turn on/off projector in node.js

Tags: node.js, ip, telnet

I have an Optoma project that I am trying to send commands to. I am able to ping the projector and connect to it with my script, but it is not turning on and off.

Here is my code:

```
const net = require('net');

// Some sample projector control codes
var NEC = {
    port: 23,
    ip: "xxx.xxx.x.xxx", // ip address
    on: Buffer.from([0x7E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x31]),
    off: Buffer.from([0x7E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x32])
};

var device = NEC;
var command = device.on;

const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(device.port, device.ip, () => {
    console.log(`Connected to projector at ${device.ip}:${device.port}`);
    client.write(command);
});

client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received data from projector:`, data.toString("hex"));
    client.end();
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Error:', err.message);
});

client.on('end', () => {
    console.log("Connection ended");
});

client.on('close', () => {
    console.log("Connection closed");
});
```

[This is the Optoma documentation with the commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0htv.png)

[I also found this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLn7T.png)

Am I writing out the commands correctly in my script?

I know the projector is able to be reached and the port is correct. Is my script the correct way to go about sending commands?

Comment: Those commands are plain text. Why don't you write them as the plain text they're supposed to be? Will make it *much* easier to see what they commands are, and make the code much more maintainable.

Comment: As for your problem, Telnet is really *line-based*, where each "command" is a single line, *including* the line-ending sequence `"\r\n"`. Will the `client.write()` function add the line-endings?

Comment: Sorry new to this. I can write the function and not the hex code? So it would be power ON and power OFF?

Comment: The sequence `0x7E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x31` is really the same as `"~0000 1"` (assuming ASCII encoding).

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked! Wish I can give you credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet is by default *line* based. That means that each "command" needs the line-ending sequence `"\r\n"`.

You need to add those to the commands you send to the device.